# jQuery scrollTop works in one snippet, doesn't in another at the same page

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

So I have a couple of screens fading in and out (steps) and what I'm trying to achieve is that when we press on a button on the first step it goes to the 2nd step Top part (which is always the main DIV containing all of them ID: `enter-give-away-now`) and then to the 3rd and the 4th etc..

I'm facing a strange issue while the 1st step is working (we press on one of the `<a>` tags and the current page fades-out while the page scrolls to the top and shows the new step) while all the other steps just won't work.. They Fade but won't scroll to the `enter-give-away-now` div top.

```
<section class="section-second">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="enter-give-away-now" class="row phone-select-row">             
            <div class="step1 marker_show">
                <h1 style="padding: 0 4px 0 4px;"><span>Pick a color.</span>Choose your Color</h1>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 next">
                    <a href="#enter-give-away-now" class="color-select-button color-select-button_4 scroll-me">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-color-select" src="img/4.png">
                        <span>White</span>
                    </a>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <!-- STEP 1 END -->

            <div class="step2 marker_show" style="display: none;">
                <h1 style="padding: 0 4px 0 4px;"><span>Title</h1>

                <div class="col-sm-4 next">

                    <a href="" id="scroll-me2" class="capacity-select-button color-select-capacity_1 scroll-me">
                        <span class="gb-amount">4<span class="gb-sign">GB</span></span>
                        <div class="capacity-info">
                            <span class="reg-price"><span class="price-label">Test builds left:</span> 3</span>
                            <span class="reg-price"><span class="price-label">Regular price:</span> 59,99$</span>
                            <span class="your-price"><span class="price-label">Your price:</span> 29,00$</span>
                        </div>  
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- STEP 2 END -->
            </div>
            </div>
            </section>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.scroll-me').bind("click", function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr("href"); // Get the target element
    var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top; // Position to scroll to
    $('html /* For FF & IE */,body /* For Chrome */').animate({
        'scrollTop': scrollToPosition
    }, 500, function(target) {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#scroll-me2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

As you can see I've tried 2 methods (`.scroll-me` works just fine on STEP1).
Step 2/3/4 are in problem and I've also tried to have it done with some other code (`#scroll-me2`) but it didn't work. Don't pay attention to the fact that I'm having both `.scroll-me` and `#scroll-me2` there, it's just there to illustrate that I've tried both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the this

```
$("#scroll-me2").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top
}, 500);
```

});

to this;

```
$("#enter-give-away-now").on('click', '#scroll-me2', function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top
}, 500);
```

});

When your jquery code rendered, the element with id #scroll-me2 is not displayed, that is why you cannot use .click() there.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a lot!